# What is a load PATH? how to verify?

Tags: command-line, path

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I am taking a look at 3.1.2, where it says

> Verify that it is correctly installed and in your load PATH

What does it mean to check that something installed is in my load PATH?
What is a load PATH, and how might I be able to read up on all these things?

New to things. I use windows. I have a unix in my computer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load Path is simply a path defined under your environment variables - ' Path ' variable.

[click here to see an image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jFHb.png)

It usually comes up in windows 10 -> when you type 'env' or 'environment' in the search bar.  -> click on ' edit the system environment variables '

Then under Environment Variables ( this is important - do not go to system variables )
click on -> path
click -> edit

[after you click edit for 'path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpP8B.png)

click -> new
just add the directory location for your sqlite3.exe ( just the folder is enough , you don't have to indicate the sqlite3.exe )
click -> ok

you're good to go :)

open a new command prompt and type sqlite3 to check.